# Template variables are not binding to component variables

Tags: angular

The values in my template are not getting bind to the component variables.

This is a segment of the template code:

```
<div class="col">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="firstName" 
        [ngModel]="shipping.firstName" #firstName="ngModel">
</div>
```

This is the component. The inputs from the template are supposed to be bind to the shipping object of the component when the "Place Order" button is clicked in the template and the placeOrder() function logs the shipping object to the console. But the shipping object shows no value when logged.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {Shipping, Payment} from '../shared/models/data-models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
  private shipping:Shipping;

  constructor() { 
    this.shipping = new Shipping();
  }

  private placeOrder() {
    console.log('shipping', this.shipping)    
  }
}
```

This is the shipping model:

```
export class Shipping {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` to allow 2 way binding

Comment: Yeah, you have to use the [(ngModel)], if you don't use the 2 way data binding, your changes will not be reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your code is set up to only allow one way binding, as you're doing `[ngModel]`.

To allow 2 way binding, which can update the value of `shipping.firstName`, you need to change it to `[(ngModel)]`.

There is more info [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) if you wish to read further